# extract tar file with txz format in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gzip, lzma, tarfile

Is there any way to extract file(filename.log.txz) with extension txz and list folder/filename after extraction in python. I tried with module tarfile which throwing error "AttributeError: module 'tarfile' has no attribute 'open'".

Note: My expectation is to extract txz file list all files/folder inside extracted file and look for required filename.

Python version: 3.6.8`

code****

```
import os
import tarfile

filename = sys.argv[1]
print(filename)

file1 = tarfile.open('{}'.format(filename), 'r')
file1.extract('path where to extract')
file1.close()
```

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tarfile.py", line 3, in 
import tarfile
File "/path/tarfile.py", line 8, in 
file1 = tarfile.open('{}'.format(filename), 'r')
AttributeError: module 'tarfile' has no attribute 'open'

**Solution:**

```
import os
import subprocess

filename = sys.argv[1]
print(filename)

subprocess.check_output("tar -xvf {filename}", shell=True)

d = os.listdir()

print(d)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), *all as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text. The code should be a [mre].

Comment: The `open()` is fine. I don't know why you're getting an error there. Are you certain that you copied and pasted your code _exactly_? Your `extract()` is wrong. You need to name the file to extract, and the path to extract into is given as `path='wheretoextract'`.

Comment: If you want to extract all of the files, then you would use `extractall(path='wheretoextract')`, not `extract()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like that

import os

```
for  file_name in os.listdir():
    if file_name.endswith(".txz"):
        os.system(f"tar -zxvf {file_name}")
```

Comment: I tried alternative way to extract txz file by executing 'tar -xvf' command with help of subprocess module(import subprocess). It worked for me. Thanx